# Android button, put image left of text, scale image automatically?

Tags: android, android-button

I want to put an image to a button.

- The image is displayed on the left of the text
- I do not want to hard-code the size of the button or button text. I want them to be sized as the user's system preferences.
- The image's height should be scaled according to the button size, not the other way round. That is, the height of the button should not change whether the image is there or not.

I do not think these requirements are rare. I have searched Stack Overflow, but none of the answers works as I intended.

Method 1) Using `<Button>`, put image using `android:drawableLeft`

- Image does not scale according to the button. The button is scaled according to the image.

Method 2) Using `<ImageButton>`

- No way to put text along with the image.

What could be a better way?

Comment: Have you uploaded all type's of image(hdpi,mdpi, etc)

Comment: I downloaded the image from Google's design site. The site provided 4 sizes (18dp, 24dp, 36dp, 48dp). I only downloaded 48dp version. but that alone contains 5 dpi files. I added all of the 5 files to my project.